# Programming my bankAccount program to deduct a set number of fees every month how?

Tags: java

I have a very  basic BankAccount class and tester.

```
/** A bank account that has a balance that can be changed by depositing and withdrawals also deducts a fee for each withdrawal and deposit.
 * 
 * @author lapenta1
 *
 */

public class BankAccount 
{

    private double balance;
    private double feeCharge;

    /** Contructs a bank account with a balance of zero
     * 
     */
    public BankAccount()
    {
        balance = 0;
        feeCharge = 2.50;
    }
    /**Constructs a bank account with a given balance
     * 
     * @param initialBalance the initial balance
     */
    public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
    {
        balance = initialBalance;
    }
    /** Deposits money into the bank account
     * 
     * @param amount the amount to deposit
     */
    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance + amount - feeCharge;
    }
    /**Withdrawals money from the bank account
     * 
     * @param amount the amount to withdrawal
     */
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance - amount - feeCharge;
    }
    /**Gets the current balance of the bank account
     * 
     * @return the current balance
     */
    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    public void deductMonthlyCharge()
    {

    }
}
```

This is the tester class

```
public class BankAccountTester 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BankAccount myWallet = new BankAccount();
        myWallet.deposit(200);
        System.out.println(myWallet.getBalance());

        BankAccount otherWallet = new BankAccount();
        otherWallet.deposit(200);
        System.out.println(otherWallet.getBalance());

    }

}
```

now I am trying to make it work so there is basically a set amount of withdrawals/deposits that can be used before the 2.50 fee is taken away every month. The only hint I have is to use math.max(actual transaction count, free transaction count) I am lost! any help?

Comment: Sounds very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716097/java-math-max-for-bank-account-transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick. Just add another `if` condition(s) to make same for deposits etc.

```
private int noOfWithdrawals = 0;
private int tresholdOfWithdrawals = 5; //Change this according to your requirement

public void withdraw(double amount)
{
    if(noOfWithdrawals <= tresholdOfWithdrawals) {
       balance = balance - amount;
       noOfWithdrawals++;
    }
    else {
       balance = balance - amount - feeCharge;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes he can, but I don't think it's required for this simple program :)

Comment: This works great thank you! But I believe I need more, the question I need to answer specifically says to allow a fixed number of free transactions every month and charge the fee for any exceeding the fixed number of free transactions (Which you provided). It then asks to add a new method to the bank Account class that deducts the monthly charge and then resets the transaction count. I guess I need a method to reset the woOfWithdrawals back to 0 at the end of every month!

Answer (score 0):

```
private double balance;
private double feeCharge;
private double freeCharge; // mutator for how many times it will be free
private double trCount = 0; //should increment after every transaction

public double deductMonthlyCharge(){
double monthlyCharge = (Math.max(trCount, freeCharge) - freeCharge) * feeCharge;
balance -= monthlyCharge;
trCount = 0;
return balance;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).